# Jquery/Bootstrap hover not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Got a page that's loaded via an ajax call. So, initially, it's empty. User enters some filter criteria which is then used to build the 'new' page via an ajax call.

Now I understand that the Jquery won't work due to the page not existing when Jquery is ready and I've read that I'll have to do something with document.on but I've no idea how to change the Jquery code to make it work.

any ideas?

Here's the existing jquery code which is used to show the Bootstrap 3 popup.

```
$( document ).ready(function()
```

{

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
    'placement': 'top'
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
 format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: 'linked',
    autoclose: 'True'
});
```

}); // End of Jquery

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle link?

Comment: I don't know how to recreate the problem with a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some extra jquery like:

```
     $(document).ajaxStop(function () {

        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
          trigger: 'hover',
          html: true,
         'placement': 'top'
       });

       $('.datepicker').datepicker({
         format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
         startView: 1,
         todayBtn: 'linked',
         autoclose: 'True'
       });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any layout page?you can put these inside ' $( document ).ready(function() '.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating my answer @user1106252.If it helped, you may tick my answer as best.